# Vertical align fixed width/height div inside variable height div

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at this **Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/cu1tpbe3/12/

How can I **vertical align** the class `.close_button` at the center of the variable height class `.container` ?

The Html looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="close_button"><img src="http://www.example.com/image.png" alt="Close" class="the_image" /></div>
<div class="the_text">Some Text</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.container {
position : relative;
width : 100%;
height : auto;
background-color: yellow;
}

.the_text {
display: table-cell;
position : relative;
padding : 0.5em 5.2% 0.5em 5.2%;
line-height : normal;
font-size : medium;
color : white;
text-align : left;
background-color: blue;
}

.close_button {
display: table-cell;
background-color: green;
float : right;
}

.the_image {
width : 30px;
height : 30px;
}
```

Comment: Why use table layout and float at the same time? Can't you just move the button div to after the text cell and remove the float?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove Float:left and add vertical align middle and place your close wrapper after the text wrapper

**HTML code**

```
<div class="container">   


<div class="the_text"> your content</div>
    <div class="close_button"><img src="http://s8.postimg.org/eq14wxj4x/inchide.png" alt="Close" class="the_image" /></div>

</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.container {
position : relative;
width : 100%;
height : auto;
background-color: yellow;
    display:table;
}

.the_text {
display: table-cell;
position : relative;
padding : 0.5em 5.2% 0.5em 5.2%;
line-height : normal;
font-size : medium;
color : white;
text-align : left;
background-color: blue;
}

.close_button {
display: table-cell;
background-color: green;
vertical-align:middle

}

.the_image {
width : 30px;
height : 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet would be to set it position:absolute; inside the containing div eg...

```
.close_button {
    position:absolute;
    top:48%;
    right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use position absolute and translate :

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.the_text {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.5em 5.2% 0.5em 5.2%;
  line-height: normal;
  font-size: medium;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: blue;
}

.close_button {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  background-color: green;
}

.the_image {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    
<div class="close_button"><img src="http://s8.postimg.org/eq14wxj4x/inchide.png" alt="Close" class="the_image" /></div>
    
<div class="the_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas aliquet sed ligula nec vulputate. Ut a libero lorem. Duis pharetra ornare imperdiet. Fusce in dignissim lectus, eget facilisis nisl. Aenean ornare euismod lacus, eu vehicula nisi dignissim ac. Morbi neque orci, fringilla sit amet vulputate eget, semper nec enim. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Cras et faucibus velit. Nullam vel vestibulum massa. Duis fermentum leo ligula, nec accumsan tellus venenatis ut. Nunc sollicitudin lectus quis justo auctor, vitae finibus dui feugiat. Nam nec elit ac dolor semper accumsan. Morbi rutrum imperdiet egestas. Nullam euismod consequat nunc quis sollicitudin. Sed at lacinia magna, non luctus massa.</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cu1tpbe3/13/)

html

```
<div class="container">



<div class="the_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas aliquet sed ligula nec vulputate. Ut a libero lorem. Duis pharetra ornare imperdiet. Fusce in dignissim lectus, eget facilisis nisl. Aenean ornare euismod lacus, eu vehicula nisi dignissim ac. Morbi neque orci, fringilla sit amet vulputate eget, semper nec enim. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Cras et faucibus velit. Nullam vel vestibulum massa. Duis fermentum leo ligula, nec accumsan tellus venenatis ut. Nunc sollicitudin lectus quis justo auctor, vitae finibus dui feugiat. Nam nec elit ac dolor semper accumsan. Morbi rutrum imperdiet egestas. Nullam euismod consequat nunc quis sollicitudin. Sed at lacinia magna, non luctus massa.</div>
    <div class="close_button"><img src="http://s8.postimg.org/eq14wxj4x/inchide.png" alt="Close" class="the_image" /></div>

</div>
```

css

```
.container {
position : relative;
width : 100%;
height : auto;
background-color: yellow;
}

.the_text {
display: table-cell;
position : relative;
padding : 0.5em 5.2% 0.5em 5.2%;
line-height : normal;
font-size : medium;
color : white;
text-align : left;
background-color: blue;
}

.close_button {
display: table-cell;
background-color: green;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.the_image {
width : 30px;
height : 30px;
}
```